# iPhone Cannot get Xcode to upgrade from 4.1 to 4.3

Tags: iphone

I have 3 logins. I installed Xcode 4.1 and it ran great. Later I upgraded, pressing the upgrade button in the App Store, and at first it seemed ok. But then I noticed only one of my logins got upgraded to Xcode 4.3.1, the other 2 logins still ran Xcode 4.1. I figured I can run the upgrade in the other 2 logins, But..... when I went to the App Store it had Xcode 4.3.1 as being installed and no button to upgrade.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4.1 usually got installed in /Developer while Xcode 4.3 is a Mac App Store App which should be located in /Applications.

Switch to one of those other accounts, open Finder, navigate to /Applications. Open Xcode in that folder, check version, if it's 4.3 then "Keep in Dock" and trash /Developer.

Comment: Hi,Ok that worked but its still mess up, is there a way to uninstall Xcode, then re-install it?????

Answer (score 2):

I think for Xcode, you have to download the whole thing and thats how it updates, so just download Xcode 4.3 and install. make sure to uninstall the other one first.

Comment: There is a way to completely uninstall Xcode put this in terminal:                                   sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all